# MySQL Empty Set Misbehavior

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am using MariaDb and PHP 7. I am wondering why I am getting wrong result all time around. Here is my MySQL Schema and Data Insertion Script-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BB_Orders`(
    `row_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
INSERT INTO `BB_Orders`(`row_id`, `order_id`) VALUES(1, '190061603-A')
INSERT INTO `BB_Orders`(`row_id`, `order_id`) VALUES(2, '190604470-A')
INSERT INTO `BB_Orders`(`row_id`, `order_id`) VALUES(3, '191206232-A')
INSERT INTO `BB_Orders`(`row_id`, `order_id`) VALUES(4, '191269277-A')
```

Here is my PHP Function Definition-

```
function ROWExists($Con, $TableName, $Condition){
    $RowID=0;
    $SelectStatement = "SELECT `row_id` FROM `".$TableName."`  WHERE ";
    foreach($Condition as $CKey=>$CValue){
        $SelectStatement.="TRIM(`".$CKey."`)=TRIM('".$CValue."') AND ";
    }
    $SelectStatement=rtrim($SelectStatement, ' AND ');
    $SelectStatement.=" LIMIT 1;";
    echo 'SELECT STATEMENT: '.$SelectStatement.PHP_EOL;
    echo $SelectStatement.PHP_EOL;
    $Resultset=mysqli_query($Con, $SelectStatement);
    if(!empty($Resultset)){
        if($Resultset->num_rows){
            while($Result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Resultset)){
                if(!empty($Result)){
                    $RowID=$Result['row_id'];                       
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    return $RowID;
}
```

I call this function using-

```
$RowID=ROWExists($Con, 'BB_Orders', array('order_id'=>'190061603-A'));
//returns the 'row_id' correct
$RowID=ROWExists($Con, 'BB_Orders', array('order_id'=>'190061603-Z'));
//returns the 'row_id' incorrect, this should have been 0, but not
```

Comment: What is the value of `$RowID`, and which row in the database corresponds to it? In the wrong case.

Comment: for the last function call it comes like Max_Row_ID+1.

Comment: Is there anything else you do, e.g. an INSERT?

Comment: No, I have not inserted.

Comment: What is the exact incorrect result you are getting for the second value?

Comment: I am getting 5 where I should get 0.

Comment: The output of `echo 'SELECT STATEMENT: '.$SelectStatement.PHP_EOL;` would be very helpful.